# Task is to fast and skip method in ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a task:

```cs
public void Main (String[] args)
{
       DoMethod();
}

public void DoMethod()
{
    Task<TResult> myTask = StartAsync();
    
    myTask.ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something");
    
        //Do some stuff
        
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            MyEditor(entry);
        }
    
        //Do some stuff
    });
}

public void MyEditor(string entry)
{
    this.entry = entry.Remove(0, 5);
}
```

But this Task is a little bit too fast.

The MyEditor Method is just formatting the entry.

My task doesn't wait for `MyEditor()` to complete the formatting.
`MyEditor()` is not async.

How I can modify a little bit to wait till `MyEditor()` is completed.

I have reduced the code to a necessary minimum so that the problem is still recognisable.
I hope I have succeeded.

Comment: Is `MyEditor` async? If so, you should await on it.

Comment: So updated a litte bit the description. `MyEditor` is not async.

Comment: @Alejandro How I can do that?

Comment: Your posted code overwrites the same class-level 'this.entry'. Without that 'this' it also wouldn't work: a change in the string parameter wouldn't make it "out", your 'entries' will not change

Comment: Sry after my second change I forget to change the whole code snippet. I updated now.

Comment: How do you know that `MyEditor` doesn't waits? It's just a normal method, execution only continues after it has fully completed. How did you measure that?

Comment: @Alejandro By adding the entry to an list. But at the end there are no entries in the list. And also during debugging it breaks in the `MyEditor` method.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want here. If you don't want your async task to run until `MyEditor()` has been called, why start it before you call it? Why do you _only_ call it as a continuation of the task? Please fix your question so it includes a proper [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Post the full relevant code. `MyEditor` is a normal sync method, therefore it doesn't "complete too fast". It neither adds  anything to any list in its current form, nor is defined anywhere what "this.entry" is. Any async task here is irrelevant for what you're asking currently.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you would need to await the mytask. If you are in a async context you could do something like the following:

```
async Task Main()
{
    List<string> entries = await StartAsync();
    
    var formattedEntries = entries.Select(e => MyEditor(e));

    foreach (var entry in formattedEntries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}

string MyEditor(string entry)
{
    return entry.ToUpper();
}

Task<List<string>> StartAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(new List<string>{"a","b"});
}
```

Or change the code to:

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> entries = StartAsync().Result;
    
    var formattedEntries = entries.Select(e => MyEditor(e));

    foreach (var entry in formattedEntries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
    }
}
```